# What's the formal definition of saying "$f$ is a function of $x$, $g$ is a function of $y$"?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, definition

I know the following definition of function (amongst others).

> Let $A,B$ be sets. A set $f\subseteq A\times B$ is said to be a function from $A$ to $B$ if the following two properties hold.
>
> - For every $a\in A$ there exists a $b\in B$ such that $(a,b)\in f$.
> - If $(a,b)\in f$ and $(a,c)\in f$, then $b=c$.
>
> In such cases we write $f:A\to B,\, f(a)=b$ .

This definition clearly says nothing about '$f$  being a function of $x$' (or $a$, or whatever you want to call your variable).

So what do people really mean when they say that "$f$ is a function of $x$"?

Answer (score 2):

They denote the *argument* of the function by any $x \in A$. The name of the variable you pick is not important, it just represents generic input into the function $f$.

Comment: I wanted to get your input on if the following is correct or not (which is good for there nature of this post as well): The value of the variable $y$ depends on the value of the variable $x$. is it incorrect to say $f$ depends on $x$ because $f$ is a function, simply a set of rules? I am just fact checking an answer on my most recent post- similar to this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687044/reading-the-notation-fx-y-in-the-context-of-dependent-and-independent-variab/3687075?noredirect=1#comment7577282_3687075

Comment: @MathDoctorR answer there is correct. You can say $y \in Y,x\in X$ and $f:X \to Y$ is given by $y = f(x)$. Similarly, if $u \in X$ then you can write $y = f(u)$ (and it would mean the same thing). What he means is $f(\cdot)$ is a set of rules, showing how to transform the input to get the output... In that sense $f$ is a set of rules that does not depend on $x$, but $f(x)$ does. For example, $f(x)=x^2$ means $f$ squares its argument. This has no explicit dependence on $x$. But once you treat $f$ as a relation, writing $y = f(x) = x^2$ then clearly in the relation $y=x^2$, $y$ depends on $x$.

Comment: I see, however what do you mean by $f(\cdot)$ is a set of rules? Isn’t $f(\cdot)$ the function value and, as you also stated, $f$ is a set of rules?

Comment: @MathDoctorR $f(\cdot)$ is not a *value*, it is a set of rules. I can use any variable to denote the actual value which $f$ will map, for example $z$. Then what $f$ will map $z$ to is denoted $f(z)$.