# Reading the notation $f(x)=y$ in the context of dependent and independent variables.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

With having a deeper understanding of functions, I am now revisiting using functions in topics such as physics and have a question regarding the notation “$f(x)=y$“ for a function $f: X \to Y$ (Where $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$).

When we say “*$f$ depends on $x$*” are we really saying “the **value** of $f$ depends on $x$“? With that said, since the value of $f$  is understood to be $y$, doesn’t that mean $y$ depends on $x$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have some set of points $D \subseteq X$ and $R \subseteq Y$. In general, the coordinates $(x,y)$ of a point $P \in D \times R$ will be completely independent of one another, as we assume them to be *independent variables*. But, in some special cases they will be related by some relation, like $f(x,y)=c$ or $f(x,y)<c$ and so on. $x^2 + y^2=r^2$ is an example. However in an even more special case, the value of one of the coordinates, say $y$, will *completely* depend on the other coordinate, $x$, via some function $f$. Formally speaking, $\forall (x,y) \in D\times R$, $y=f(x)$. In this way, we can reduce all problems involving *two* variables, $x$ and $y$ to problems about $x$ and $f(x)$, which is a problem of *one* variable. Remember that $f$ is a function, a list of rules to follow, whereas $f(x) \in R$ and is a value.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth response. So the value, $y$, of the function $f$ depends on $x$ according to your answer? I believe what I am trying to clear up is thats what we mean when we say $f$ depends on $x$.

Comment: The value of the variable $y$ depends on the value of the variable $x$. It is incorrect to say $f$ depends on $x$ because $f$ is a *function*, simply a set of rules. It  **is** true that $f$ takes $x$ as an argument in its list of rules, so it is correct to say $f(x)$ depends on $x$, but the list of rules that define $f$ are the same no matter what value $x$ takes out of all possible values in $X$.